# Delete/replace or edit columns of an access table when updating daily

Tags: vba, replace

I support an access database for which the primary data resource is a text file imported daily.  The fields in the text file are variable.  When the fields change, it impacts multiple tables within my access database, so I'm maintaining them dynamically by importing the data into a temp table and aligning the columns and data types of the rest with a "master structure" table.  It contains the field names, data types, lengths and so on.  This master table will be changed every time the text file changes, but this approach seems to fit my users' needs.

My question:  would it be better to systematically delete/replace my existing access tables daily, or systematically alter the tables to match the changes in the data?  Are there any performance or size repercussions to deleting and replacing tables on a daily basis with VBA and SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no size repercussions for deleting and replacing Access tables using  the VBA.

This operation however could have a performance hit , but it will be negligible if number of your tables are small.

So the answer to your question depends the size and number of your tables.

If the number is large then altering the tables method gives you a noticable performace over deleting and replacing method.

Comment: Thank you S Nash. I'm dealing with only 3-5 tables, so I'll assume delete/replace is a safe approach for this situation. I greatly appreciate your feedback.